# Android - How to Unblock Your IP address from Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

I don't know why, But I am unable to store data in the Firebase database using my `IP address` but can Store data from different `IP address`. Till Morning it was Working Fine but suddenly this happens. Now I cannot retrieve data from Firebase from my `IP address`. Has anyone had any solutions or suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use VPN to change your IP and open Firebase,
My country's whole IPs are blocked by Firebase! And this solution is the only one that worked for me.

update:
If you intend to distribute your app in one of these countries (Crimea, Cuba, Iran, North Korea, Sudan, and Syria) then your app users will also need to use VPN.

Comment: Just for curiosity, can you tell which is that country where Firebase is blocked?

Comment: @MaulikHirani There are several countries (Crimea, Cuba, Iran, North Korea, Sudan, and Syria)